# Mscgen Templates

Tags: sequence-diagram, mscgen

I'm using [mscgen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/) to make Message Sequence Charts. Can I use a different template to improve the graphic of my diagram, or can I use another similar tool (if yes, what?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with mscgen.js: https://mscgen.js.org

The templates are behind the sprocket button that appears after it rendered the chart (see picture below)

- There's some experimental styles too. To use them you can use https://mscgen.js.org/index.html?debug=true
- There's a [cli](https://github.com/mscgenjs/mscgenjs-cli) and an [atom package](https://atom.io/packages/mscgen-preview) that have the same styles (and javascript rendering engine).

[image: mscgen_js with the wobbly fountainpen style]